# Building OpenCV 3.3.0 program with Bazel compiler produces linking errors

Tags: c++, opencv, tensorflow, bazel

I'm trying to use Bazel to compile an OpenCV based C++ program, and I'm facing an issue.

I created my project with this `WORKSPACE` file:

```
new_local_repository(
name = "opencv330",
path = "/usr/opencv330",
build_file = "opencv330.BUILD",)
```

and this `opencv330.BUILD` file:

```
cc_library(
name = "opencv330",
srcs = glob(["lib/*.so*"]),
hdrs = glob(["include/**/*.hpp", "include/**/*.h", 
"/include/opencv2/*.h", "/include/opencv2/*.hpp"]),
includes = ["include"],
visibility = ["//visibility:public"], 
linkstatic = 1,
)
c_binary(
    name = "main",
    srcs = ["main.cc"],
    deps = [
    "@opencv330//:opencv330"
    ],
)
```

As an example, I try to use the simple Opencv program, which reads video from a file:

```
CvCapture* g_capture = NULL; // Структура для видеофайла
g_capture = cvCreateFileCapture("1080.mp4");
IplImage* frame;
frame = cvQueryFrame(g_capture);
cvNamedWindow("original", 0); // Создание окна


while(1){
 frame = cvQueryFrame(g_capture); // Последовательное       чтение кадров

 if (!frame) { // Конец файла, кадров больше нет
        break;
    }

  // Display the resulting frame
 cvShowImage("original", frame); // Отображение кадра

  // Press  ESC on keyboard to exit
  char c = cvWaitKey(15); // Ожидание 15 мс, получение ASCII кода клавиши
  if (c == 27) { // Если Esc - выход из цикла
      break;
  }
}

// When everything done, release the video capture object
cvReleaseCapture(&g_capture); // Закрытие файла

// Closes all the frames
cvDestroyAllWindows();
```

But now I have error:

> In file included from ./tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h:19:0,
>                    from ./tensorflow/cc/framework/ops.h:21,
>                    from ./tensorflow/cc/ops/const_op.h:19,
>                    from tensorflow/examples/label_image/main.cc:41: /home/viol5728/tensorflow-r1.7/third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor:1:42:
>   fatal error: unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor: No such file or directory
>
> ## include "unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor"

But file Tensor is in the directory "unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor"! 
(Tensorflow 1.7)

There is two directories in system:

1)"/home/viol5728/tensorflow-r1.7/third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11"

2) "/usr/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen"

So how can I point Bazel to first directory?????